# using t sql sp to build xml and excute sp to insert into tables

Tags: xml, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am a bit new with t-sql and I have a store procedure that builds an xml blob. How do I build an insert query to insert the xml created from the stored procedure into a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example for you that should self extract inside SQL Management Studio 2005 and up:

```
DECLARE @Xml XML = '<Root><Instance Id="1" Val="Hello">There</Instance><Instance Id="2" Val="How">Are You?</Instance></Root>'

SELECT
  x.query('.') AS queryingtheentireNode
, x.value('@Id', 'int') AS AttributeForId
, x.value('@Val', 'varchar(16)') AS AttributeForVal
, x.value('.', 'varchar(16)') AS TextInsideTheNode
FROM @Xml.nodes('/Root/Instance') AS y(x)
```

Essentially xml is a three dimensional object.  With the from states I am taking a single variables and expanding it dimensionally into more by saying 'nodes'.  I am then specifying the root node and then the only other child node off of that.  Then I abbreviate it y(x).  I don't know why MS requires two values like that but if you do 'as x' it will fail.  Then I can 'query' this newly referenced nodes as x.query.  Or I can find a specific 'value' from it.
I would look on google for tsql xml nodes, xml query, and xml value.  There are other flavors but IMHO these methods are easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the help I had used something similar to store the xml blob. 

```declare @XMLUsers xml set @XMLUsers = (Select (Select U.UserGUID As [@UserID], U.Login AS [@Login], U.Password AS [@Password], U.PasswordDate As [@PasswordDate], U.FName As [@FName], U.LName AS [@LName] From UserSettings..tblUsers As U```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```sql
INSERT myschemafortable.xmldate(xmlblob)
EXEC myschemaforsp.build_xml_blob;
```

More info you can get from [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381(v=sql.105).aspx#OtherTables).